# Количество повторений максимального элемента в последовательности

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Условие (переведено):

> Написать программу, которая получает целое число N, а затем
> последовательность из N целых чисел. Программа должна вывести
> количество повторений максимального элемента в последовательности.
> Запрещено использовать массивы

Примеры:

Входные данные
`0`
Результат работы
`0`

Входные данные
`5 2 6 6 3 -5`
Результат работы
`2`

Входные данные
`10 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1`
Результат работы
`10`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int i, j, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> n;
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (n == i && n == j)
            {
                ++count;
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
    std::cout << "repeated elements  count" << count;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109554/discussion-on-question-by-vardan-------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В измененном варианте задание - вот, все просто:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    if (N == 0) 
    {
        cout << "0\n";
        return 0;
    }
    int max, maxcount = 1;
    cin >> max;
    for(int i = 1, m; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cin >> m;
        if (max < m)
        {
            max = m;
            maxcount = 1;
        }
        else if (max == m)
        {
            maxcount++;
        }
    }
    cout << maxcount << endl;
}
```

Comment: Похоже на моё решение. Или я ошибаюсь, и у меня не правильно?

Comment: @Стас Да мы их одновременно написали просто :) Я решил не полагаться на -2147483649, и просто первое же число (а оно точно есть, натуральное нулем не бывает :)) объявил начальным максимумом.

Comment: Ваше решение зависит от компилятора. С gcc проходит, VC++ 2017 ругается на вашу магическую константу и дает неверное решение...

Comment: Я в VS не пишу, не знал : (

Comment: здесь проблема в том что когда вводится 0 программа не возвращает ответ 0...

Comment: Harry  как можно это изменить???

Comment: Ну, это противоречит условию, 0 - **не** натуральное число. Но... "любой каприз за ваши деньги" :) - см. измененный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если перевод

> Программа должна вывести количество повторений максимального элемента
> в последовательности

правильный, то вот:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int find_reps(int n){
    int num, reps = 0;
    long long max = -2147483649ll;

    if (n == 0 || n == 1){cin >> num; return 0;}

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        cin >> num;
        if (num > max){
            max = num;
            reps = 0;
        }
        if (num == max) reps++;

    }
    return reps;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << find_reps(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь создаётся переменная `max` с значением *-2147483649* (чтобы любое число типа `int` было больше его). Если `n == 1`, можно сразу вернуть 0 повторений. Далее в цикле вводятся значения (их можно писать через пробел). Если число большего максимума (значит, это новый максимум) - оно сохраняется в переменную и количество повторений обнуляется (нашли новый максимум, он не повторился ещё ни разу). Ну и если введённое число равно максимуму, значит оно повторяется. Когда цикл завершится - можно вернуть повторения.

Comment: Да, ваше решение, скажем так, не совсем верное - например, VC++ дает неверный ответ, смотрите сами: https://rextester.com/VJUN19630 На gcc прокатывает, но, вообще говоря, ваша "волшебная константа" не совсем верна.

Comment: Могу только исправить ответ, удалить не получится...

Comment: Исправьте на `long long max = -2147483649ll;` - вы даете константу, которая выходит за пределы `int`, но не говорите ее тип. Так что по умолчанию получается `int` со всеми вытекающими...

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Comment: Стас спасибо вам за решение задачи! было трудно переводить смысл но в итоге все получилось как надо ))

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
int n;
std::cin >> n;
int num, max, count;
if(n == 1){
std::cin >> num;
}
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  std::cin >> num;
  if(num > max) {
    max = num;
    count = 0;
  }
  if(num == max) {
    count++;
  }
 }
  std::cout << count;
 }
```

Comment: Это значит что остальные ответы вас не устроили или вы просто решили дописать свой?

Comment: нет с помощью ваших ответов решил просто дописать мой вариант. Еще раз спасибо вам за ответ